# What's this "from ... to" in my mysql table schema?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration

I wrote a simple rails migration to set the default value on the `name` column of my `gardens` table:

```
class ChangeColumnDefaultToGarden < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up 
    change_column_null :gardens, :name, false
    change_column_default :gardens, :name, from: nil, to: ""
    change_column_null :gardens, :square_feet, false
    change_column_null :gardens, :zone, false
  end

  def down
    change_column_null :gardens, :name, true
    change_column_default :gardens, :name, from: "", to: nil
    change_column_null :gardens, :square_feet, true
    change_column_null :gardens, :zone, true
  end

end
```

When I run the migration and describe the table I see this:

```
mysql> describe gardens;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default              | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                 | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | ---
:from: ''
:to:
 |                |
| square_feet | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
| zone        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
| garden_type | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
| user_id     | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL                 |                |
| created_at  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| updated_at  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.17 sec)
```

What is that `:from: ""` and `:to:`?  I'm not familiar with that mysql syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have incorrect call to [`#change_column_default`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQL/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column_default) correct way is:

```
def up
   change_column_default(:gardens, :name, "") 
end
```

But you can combine change null and default into a single call to [`change_column_null`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQL/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column_null):

```
def up 
  change_column_null :gardens, :name, false, ""
end

def down
  change_column_null :gardens, :name, true
end
```